# How to recalculate elements with IEnumerable.Select?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

```
IEnumerable<MyType> list = new List<MyType>{
    new{Num=0, Text="ABC"},
    new{Num=0, text="DEF"},
    new{Num=0, text="GHI"} }
```

I need to get element index in Num field:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> result = new List<MyType>{
    new{Num=1, Text="ABC"},
    new{Num=2, text="DEF"},
    new{Num=3, text="GHI"} }
```

Is it possible to do it with some LINQ-based construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = list.Select(
    (element, index) => new MyType { Num = index + 1, Text = element.Text }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newList = list.Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, list.Length),
    (item, i) => new { Num = i, item.text}).ToList();
```